# How do I cd into an external ssd in Anaconda Prompt on Windows 11

Tags: windows

I can only `cd ..` as far back as C drive

```
(base) C:\>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows-SSD
 Volume Serial Number is 1892-FFE1

 Directory of C:\

2022-12-04  02:17 AM    <DIR>          DRIVER
2021-02-12  01:08 PM    <DIR>          Drivers
2022-06-26  02:31 PM            12,288 DumpStack.log
2022-12-04  06:48 AM    <DIR>          ESD
2022-05-05  06:55 AM    <DIR>          MinGW
2022-05-15  09:49 PM    <DIR>          msys64
2023-01-07  02:41 PM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
2023-01-16  02:12 PM    <DIR>          Program Files
2023-01-17  07:12 AM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
2022-05-14  05:32 PM                 0 Recovery.txt
2022-05-18  02:19 PM    <DIR>          texlive
2023-01-16  02:13 PM    <DIR>          Users
2023-01-16  02:18 PM    <DIR>          Windows
2023-01-16  02:19 PM    <DIR>          Windows.old
               2 File(s)         12,288 bytes
              12 Dir(s)  23,919,964,160 bytes free
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I `cd` into an external SSD?

If the external drive is letter is `D` then the command would be:

```
cd /d d:
```

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> CD [/D] [drive:][path]
> CD [..]
> ```
>
> **Key**
>
> `/D` : change the current DRIVE in addition to changing folder.

Source: [CD Change Directory - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)